# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable...2D array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, typeerror, iterable

I'm trying to set a class property of a cell contained in the multidimensional array Board.grid.  I get the following error message:

```
  File "newbs1.py", line 133, in get_and_set_board_item
    self.grid[x, y].set_cell(value, secondary)
  File "newbs1.py", line 129, in __getitem__
    return self.grid[x][y]
  File "newbs1.py", line 128, in __getitem__
    x, y = tup
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The idea of having the x and y entered how they are came from a post by someone else, it fixed their problem but it hasn't worked for me.

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = []
        self.width = 10
        self.height = 10

    def __getitem__(self, tup):
        x, y = tup
        return self.grid[x][y]

    def get_and_set_board_item(self, x, y, value, secondary):
        print (x, y, value, secondary)
        self.grid[(x, y)].set_cell(value, secondary)


class Cell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_ship = False
        self.is_hidden = False
        self.ship_symbol = ""

    def set_cell(self, value, secondary):
        if secondary == None:
            self.is_hidden = value
        else:
            self.is_ship = value
            self.ship_symbol = secondary
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks, but on **line:133**, `self.grid[(x, y)].set_cell(value, secondary)`, it doesn't look like the tuple `(x, y)` is  a **Cell** type.

#### Maybe try:

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = []
        self.width = 10
        self.height = 10

    def __getitem__(self, tup):
        x, y = tup
        return self.grid[x][y]

    def get_and_set_board_item(self, x, y, value, secondary):
        print (x, y, value, secondary)
        # add this line #
        self.grid[x][y] = Cell() # set this to a cell type
        # ************* #
        self.grid[x][y].set_cell(value, secondary)


class Cell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_ship = False
        self.is_hidden = False
        self.ship_symbol = ""

    def set_cell(self, value, secondary):
        if secondary == None:
            self.is_hidden = value
        else:
            self.is_ship = value
            self.ship_symbol = secondary
```